# Resetting a JDBC connection state (c3p0)

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, c3p0

What is the recommended way to reset a C3P0 managed connection to its initial state?

I am using the Microsoft JDBC driver and setting a `SET ROWCOUNT 1` on one connection. This results in all queries executed by that connection to return only one row *even after the connection has been returned to the pool and later fetched again*. Should I be resetting the values explicitly `onCheckin` or `onCheckout`?

**Main class**

```java
    import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;
    import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    
    import java.sql.Connection; 
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    
    public class Main {
    
        final ComboPooledDataSource cpds;
        
        Main() throws PropertyVetoException {
            cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
            cpds.setDriverClass("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            cpds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://10.42.62.41:1433;databaseName=mach;integratedSecurity=false;SendStringParametersAsUnicode=true;applicationName=panda;");
            cpds.setUser("testuser");
            cpds.setPassword("welcome123");
            cpds.setInitialPoolSize(0);
            cpds.setMinPoolSize(1);
            cpds.setMaxPoolSize(1);
            cpds.setConnectionCustomizerClassName("C3p0ConnectionCustomizer");
            cpds.setDescription("Netbeans test project");
        }
        
        Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{
            return cpds.getConnection();
        }
        
        public static void main(String[] args) throws PropertyVetoException, SQLException {
            Main m = new Main();
            
            try(Connection connection = m.getConnection()){
                Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
                stmt.execute("SET ROWCOUNT 1");
            }
            
            try(Connection connection = m.getConnection()){
                try(Statement stmt = connection.createStatement()) {
                    int cnt = 0, rsCnt = 0;
                    boolean results = stmt.execute("select * from Foo; select * from Bar");
                    if(results) {
                        do {
                            rsCnt++;
                            ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
                            while(rs.next()) {
                                cnt++;
                            }
                            System.out.println(rsCnt + " -> " + cnt);
                            rs.close();
                            results = stmt.getMoreResults();
                            cnt = 0;
                        } while (results);
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    
    }
```

**Customizer** - Mainly to see the connection being used.

```java
    import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.AbstractConnectionCustomizer;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    
    public class C3p0ConnectionCustomizer extends AbstractConnectionCustomizer {
    
        @Override
        public void onAcquire(Connection c, String pdsIdt) {
            try (Statement stmt = c.createStatement()) {
                stmt.execute("SET ROWCOUNT 0");
            } catch(SQLException sqle) {
                sqle.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onCheckOut(Connection c, String pdsIdt) {
            System.out.println("Checked out " + c + " [" + pdsIdt + "]");
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onCheckIn(Connection c, String pdsIdt) throws SQLException {
            System.out.println("Checking in " + c + " [" + pdsIdt + "]");
    
        }
    
    }
```

Without the `SET ROWCOUNT 1` line, more rows are returned by the above queries. The customizer logging shows that the same connection is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could argue that, ideally, code that calls `SET ROWCOUNT 1` really should "clean up after itself" by making sure that it calls `SET ROWCOUNT 0` before releasing the connection back to the pool.

However, if we cannot absolutely guarantee such behaviour then it seems quite reasonable to simply move your `SET ROWCOUNT 0` call from the `onAcquire` method to the `onCheckIn` method. It would result in an extra round-trip for each check-in, even if resetting `ROWCOUNT` was not really necessary, but a `SET ROWCOUNT 0` would be a relatively inexpensive operation.

(I just tried it with c3p0-0.9.5.2 and mssql-jdbc, and moving `SET ROWCOUNT 0` to the `onCheckIn` method had the desired effect.)

Comment: Would it not be better to reset the value onCheckIn rather than onCheckOut? I understand from the c3p0 docs that checkin is handled asynchronously whereas checkout is synchronous in nature.